# select2 : ajax and custom coordinates [lon,lat] tags

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am building a geo search box using select2.

The user should be able to input a city, a country or decimal coordinates [lon,lat].
The city/country is queried on the server via an ajax call

Is it possible to prevent the ajax call when the input "[" is detected and to create the search choice only if lon,lat matches the regex below ?

```
^[-+]?(180(\.0{1,15})?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d{1,15})?),[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d{1,15})?|90(\.0{1,15})?)$
```

if the user tries to close the [lon,lat] tag with "]" without matching the regex it should display a custom message

my current code without the coordinates tags is :

```
    $('.select2-search').select2({
        placeholder: 'Country, city or [lon,lat]',
        multiple: true,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        maximumSelectionSize: 4,
        ajax: {
            url: "/citiesCountries",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function(term) {
                return {
                    search: term
                };
            },
            results: function(data) {
                return { results: data}
            }
       }
    });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **transport**, example:

```
$('.select2-search').select2({
    placeholder: 'Country, city or [lon,lat]',
    multiple: true,
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    maximumSelectionSize: 4,
    ajax: {
        url: "/citiesCountries",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function(term) {
            return {
                search: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data) {
            return { results: data}
        },
        transport: function(params){
            params.beforeSend = function(request){
                alert('your regex condition here');
            };
            return $.ajax(params);
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks, it works! I ended up modifying the plugin code as it better suited my needs. You can find more info here on the search term format by regular expression (https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2397)